# Official link format for creating a Microsoft Outlook (windows live mail) calendar event

Tags: html, outlook, calendar

Can anyone link to the official documentation of how Microsoft Outlook (online version) calendar hyperlinks should be formatted? Or failing that, explain how I should do this? In particular, I want to know about DateTime formats.

I want to provide a link on a webpage to allow a user to add an event to their Microsoft Outlook (online) calendar.

I have followed the format generated by this tool: https://www.labnol.org/apps/calendar.html but am confused about how to handle adding events across daylight savings changes. In the front end of the site, I always display local times (this is a UK only site). Internally we convert those to UTC. I'm not sure what Microsoft Outlook expects. I use UTC with Google calendar and that works correctly.

From the above link, I see a DateTime offset is included in the DateTime format e.g.

```
startdt=2022-04-02T11%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00
```

which without the URL encoding is:

```
startdt=2022-04-02T11:00:00+00:00
```

So the DateTime offset shown here is 0 hours 0 minutes.

***Should I keep the time as UTC and vary offset accordingly depending on the time of year, or should I leave the offset at 00:00 and then adjust my times depending on the time of year?***

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN REMOVE THE OFFSET AND KEEPS THE TIME HOUR AND DATE OR DATE ONLY.

[https://outlook.live.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose?allday=false&enddt="+variableOfDateTime+"&path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addevent&startdt="+variableDateTime""](https://outlook.live.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose?allday=false&enddt=%22+variableOfDateTime+%22&path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addevent&startdt=%22+variableDateTime%22%22) title="Save Event in my Calendar"

Comment: please stop screaming